Opinions on which Passover Jesus overturned the tables, etc
In John 2:13-16 Jesus goes to the first Passover of his ministry period listed in the Gospels. In this scene, he famously overturns the money changers' tables, made a scourge and drove out the people conducting business in the temple complex.
Later, in Matthew 21:12-13, Mark 11:15-17, and Luke 19:45-46, the same event occurs, but this time at the final Passover of his ministry period.
John makes no mention of the event happening at the final Passover. The Synoptics make no mention of the event happening at a previous Passover.
Given the proximity of the event to the time of Jesus' baptism in John, and the age of the temple according to the priests at the time the scene occurred (forty-six years according to John 2:20), John does give us a historical landmark event by which we can conceivably date this first Passover of his ministry period, and by extension the event in question, to 29 CE. And the questions that resulted in this information were provoked specifically by Jesus' actions. Ergo, if he didn't overturn the tables, drive people out with a scourge, etc., the priests never would have indignantly questioned who he thought he was to do those things.
In which case, there does seem to be validity to the timing of John's account.
So, my question, for which I seek opinions, is whether the Synoptics added the scene to the final Passover since none of them cover the first Passover of the ministry period. It was an important event that needed to be told. But they don't discuss the Passover during which John claimed it happened.
By contrast, the story of the woman washing Jesus' feet and drying them with her hair, then anointing his feet with costly ointment . . . this is mentioned in all four Gospels. But Luke mentions it, in surprising detail by comparison, well before Passion week. Luke's version is in the same town, at the house of a man named Simon. The woman performs the same tasks. She even uses the same ointment. Relative to the purpose for which she saved the costly ointment, the version that has it during Passion week seems more chronologically sound. But there's no doubt that Luke is recounting the same event, if chronologically misplaced.
So, I do see a precedent to speculate that some key stories may have been told at random to make sure they were told (which is not to say they were manufactured, only that they were told out of order where necessary to ensure inclusion).
Alternately, could the duplication of the temple scene be something that happened twice? I can fully appreciate people leaving if there's a crazy guy whipping them. But I can just as easily imagine them getting angry, going home and complaining about what happened, and then coming right back during other festivals or feasts in succeeding years. Politically or legally speaking in a secular sense, Jesus didn't have the authority to prohibit, punish, or put them to death. If it angered him the first time, it would anger him in succeeding instances. Jesus did go to Jerusalem, knowing he was going to be taken and put to death. Perhaps he repeated the action in order to provoke the religious leadership?
Any thoughts?

This question is similar to: One Temple cleansing or Two? and several others. May I suggest that you tweak the question and use it as an answer in one of the existing threads?

I agree - this is actually an answer to the other question.

Why did someone downvote this question? It's similar to the other, which I didn't know about, but it's not the same. I still want opinions on what others think. What is the basis for closing it? Some of you people are just too gung-ho about stepping on people, driving down their reputation, deciding by your whimsical opinion what has a right to be there and be answered. If the other question was going to elicit the same responses, I would have deleted the question myself.
